# extracting values from .sql file

Tags: php, regex

i have a .sql file  which contains the exported code from some database

```
   # Dump File
    # Database is ported from MS Access
    CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `movedb`;
    # Table structure for table 'test_prefixSwitchboard Items'
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test_prefixSwitchboard Items`;
    CREATE TABLE `tbl` (
      `x` INTEGER NOT NULL, 
      `y` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
      `z` VARCHAR(255)
    ) ENGINE=innodb DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    SET autocommit=1;
    #
    # Dumping data for table 'Switchboard Items'
    #
    INSERT INTO `tbl` ( `x`, `y`, `z`) VALUES ( '111' , '111' ,'111');
    INSERT INTO `tbl` ( `x`, `y`, `z`) VALUES ( '222' , '2222' ,'222');
    INSERT INTO `tbl` ( `x`, `y`, `z`) VALUES ( '333' , '333' ,'333');
```

i want to put it's values into my database ,  my column names are diferent from .sql file column names so i need to only extract the values i.e

```
'111' , '111' ,'111'
'222' , '2222' ,'222'
'333' , '333' ,'333'
```

and there might be some other tables in that file so its important to get this table only .

i usually don't ask question without providing any code of my own , but i suck at regex stuff and this seems very complected at least to me.

**i have to add , someone is going to uupload this file every couple of day . and i want to add some values to current values before inserting them on my database so i'm more comfortable to use regex**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match the `VALUES (` portion, then capture the text from then on until you hit `);` and the end of the string, like this:

```
preg_match_all( '/VALUES\s+\(\s+(.*?)(?=\);\s*$)/', $file, $matches);

foreach( $matches[1] as $match) {
    echo $match;
}
```

This will print:

```
'111' , '111' ,'111' 
'222' , '2222' ,'222' 
'333' , '333' ,'333'
```

**Edit:** For table names, you would add the table name to the regex, then churn through the column names since you don't care about capturing them like this:

```
preg_match_all( '/`tbl`.*?VALUES\s+\(\s+(.*?)(?=\);\s*$)/m', $file, $matches);
```

Where you can change `tbl` to anything you need.

Comment: thanx , what if i want to include the name of table in the reges (there might be other tables in the file) some thing like `preg_match_all( '/`tbl` (*)\s+\VALUES\s+\(\s+(.*?)(?=\);)/', $file, $matches);
` ?`

Comment: @max - I've updated my answer to show how you can restrict it to a specific table.

Comment: thank you it works great , but why did you use `$matches[1]` ? whats in `$matches[0]` ?

Comment: Do a `var_dump( $matches)` and you'll see! It's the complete matched string, which isn't what you want (you want the captured text, in `[1]`).

Comment: sorry to bother you but i have one more question about empty spaces between Parenthesis and values in this code `(\s+(.*?)(?=\)`  i think its `\s+` what if i want to make this optional ? i've tried (\s+?) but it doesn't work

Comment: Change the `+` sign to `*`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of REGEX, a simple and quick method is to import your .sql file into MySQL, and then export them as CSV.

You can create a temporary database for not diluting others databases.

If this is a one time job, you do it in phpMyAdmin(manually, simple).

If that's a repetitive job, you can make a script to auto import sql and export csv through command line.

Comment: Instead of exporting to a CSV I recommend building a INSERT/UPDATE script based on this table to "move" data into your target table(s).

Comment: @ZombieHunter, thanks for the tip. I just noted max's object is about transferring data from db.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solve by just import the table into database with temporary name and then get data through query and drop the table.

```
# Dump File
# Database is ported from MS Access
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `movedb`;
# Table structure for table 'test_prefixSwitchboard Items'
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test_prefixSwitchboard Items`;
CREATE TABLE `tbl` (
  `x` INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  `y` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
  `z` VARCHAR(255)
) ENGINE=innodb DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
SET autocommit=1;
#
# Dumping data for table 'Switchboard Items'
#
INSERT INTO `tbl` ( `x`, `y`, `z`) VALUES ( '111' , '111' ,'111');
INSERT INTO `tbl` ( `x`, `y`, `z`) VALUES ( '222' , '2222' ,'222');
INSERT INTO `tbl` ( `x`, `y`, `z`) VALUES ( '333' , '333' ,'333');

CREATE TABLE `tb2` (
  `x2` INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  `y2` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
  `z2` VARCHAR(255)
) ENGINE=innodb DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
SET autocommit=1;

insert into tb2 (x2,y2,z2) select x, y, z from tbl;
drop table tbl;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b97ce/1/0

Answer (score 0):

The even quicker way, if this is not something you are doing everyday, is to actually edit the whole file in an editor that allows you to "search/replace". For example EditPLus. You would then replace everything that matches

```
`tbl` ( `x`, `y`, `z`)
```

to

```
`your_tbl` ( `your_x`, `your_y`, `your_z`)
```

And then save, import edited file.

I know it's not a really technical solution to the problem, but it is very easy to do :)